# Proving/Disproving a limit with absolute value

Tags: limits, absolute-value

Assume f: R -> R, if |f(x) − f(y)| = |x − y|,
Then limx→∞ |f(x)| = ∞

I'm new to limits and was wondering how would I prove/disprove such a claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ |a| = |b| \Rightarrow a = \pm b$

so $ f(x) - f(y) = x-y \Rightarrow f(x) = x+c , c\in R$ (we get this by putting y = 0)

or

similarly $f(x) = -x +c$

and now we can easily verify that the limit is true...

Comment: Doesn't it limit the proof when you take y = 0? if you put any other y, would f(x) = +-x + c - y?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by "limit the proof" how did I limit it the proof is done with the given conditions and that's all, If there are any inconsistencies then tell me but I think the proof is complete...